# Problem in calling intent Dialogflow call intent based on the your say when multiple context are active and get device ID

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to create a pizza ordering bot and also it allow the user to modify the order like "Add item" , "remove item" and modify the quantity of the existing order.

**My order was taken successful, but I am unable to call modify intent based on the user utterances.**

**I also want the email ID from the device or any other unique ID to recognize the user.(Using dialog-flow fulfillment's).**

### Flow:

Step 1: welcome intent => then ordering pizza intent (ask for type/quantity/toppings) => then order confirm intent.

Step 2: User says "confirm order" it will display order and confirmed. At this session "update-Order", "add-item", "remove-item" these three context will be active. Based on the user utterance the intent will called. **But its not working it went to default fallback intent. When I say modify order it's not going to update-order intent**

Comment: Have you used the Dialogflow simulator to ensure the contexts are available?

Comment: Yes, once the order confirmed i made the three context active. I am able to saw those on the simulator.